# WritableField field_from_native returned value not used in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

maybe this is not an issue but it's just me that I don't understand well how to use your framework (this is both my first time with python, django and rest_framework all together).

I've created a simple serializers.WritableField

```
 class JsonField(serializers.WritableField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)

    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, reverted_data):
        return json.dumps(data.get(field_name, '{}'))
```

This JsonField is used like this:

```
class QuestionCreationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    constraints = JsonField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('group',)
```

in out DB constraints are like this:

```
constraints = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default='{}', blank=True)
```

The method `field_from_native` is called correctly and it's doing it's job returning (I've checked) the value I want it to return. 
The problem is that that value returned is not used in the Serializer that use JsonField.

Instead if I just implement `from_native` (but I need to use `field_from_native`) it works perfectly as intended.

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Can you show us, how do you use this field..

Comment: I've updated the question with more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return value from `field_from_native`, you do it this way:

```
def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
    into[field_name] = json.dumps(data.get(field_name, '{}'))
```

This should work as expected. Although I recommend you to use [django-json-field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) instead. The logic of encoding/decoding field data should be embedded inside models, not the serializer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the issue using django-json-field :)